# How can I combine two different data frames into a pivot table and then add in columns to calculate the difference in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have two pivot tables of insurance claims by month, vendor and another source, one pivot table has data for 2 months (say this is the "old" table), the other has data for the same 2 months + 1 more (call this the "new" table). What i'd like to do is put them side by side, and add two additional columns that subtract the difference by month of the new minus old, and then calculate the percentage change. The two tables are based on two data frames, df and hdf.

Here is what the tables look like (old table that is, the new just includes 202003):

```
        PAID                                                   
SOURCE                       IP          OP           PR
CLAIM_VENDOR PYYMM                                                             
VENDOR 1     202001         NaN        0.00          NaN 
             202002         NaN        0.00      3150.00
VENDOR 2     202001         NaN         NaN   1197812.00
             202002         NaN         NaN   1837917.00
VENDOR 3     202001  9005941.61  8987012.39  16890979.44
             202002  5158238.02  7796918.67  16888689.98
```

```
Old = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                     values = ["PAID"], 
                     index = ["CLAIM_VENDOR","PYYMM"], 
                     columns = ["SOURCE"],
                     aggfunc=np.sum
                     )

New = pd.pivot_table(hdf, 
                     values = ["PAID"], 
                     index = ["CLAIM_VENDOR","PYYMM"], 
                     columns = ["SOURCE"],
                     aggfunc=np.sum
                     )
```

So the ultimate goal is to get them side by side, and then add 6 additional columns that take the difference of each "source" by month and then also the percentage difference. It is expected that the new would have different values even for the same months for this project.

Sorry if i did bad stackoverflow formatting, haven't used this before.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create old table
old_df_index = pd.MultiIndex(
    [["VENDOR 1", "VENDOR 2", "VENDOR 3"], ["202001", "202002"]],
    [[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
    names=["CLAIM_VENDOR", "PYYMM"]
)
old_df_index.name = "SOURCE"
old_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "IP": [None, None, None, None, 9005941.61, 5158238.02],
        "OP": [0, 0, None, None, 8987012.39, 7796918.67],
        "PR": [None, 3150, 1197812, 1837917, 16890979.44, 16888689.98]
    },
    index=old_df_index,
    columns=pd.Index(["IP", "OP", "PR"], name="PAID")
)

# Create new table
new_df_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["VENDOR 1", "VENDOR 2", "VENDOR 3"], ["202001", '202002', "202003"]],
    names=["CLAIM_VENDOR", "PYYMM"]
)
new_df_index.name = "SOURCE"
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "IP": [None, None, None, None, None, 8675309*1.5, 9005941.61*1.7, 5158238.02*1.9, 2020567*2.1],
        "OP": [0, 0, 0, None, None, None, 8987012.39*1.25, 7796918.67*1.45, 125964816*1.65],
        "PR": [None, 3150*0.75, 2210*0.7, 1197812*0.9, 1837917*0.99, 1818956*0.6, 16890979.44*1.2, 16888689.98*1.1, 74747687*3.1]
    },
    index=new_df_index,
    columns=pd.Index(["IP", "OP", "PR"], name="PAID")
)

# We want the index to include CLAIM_VENDOR, PYYMM and PAID for the join below
old_df_for_join = (
    old_df.melt(ignore_index=False)
    .reset_index()
    .set_index(["CLAIM_VENDOR", "PYYMM", "PAID"])
)
new_df_for_join = (
    new_df.melt(ignore_index=False)
    .reset_index()
    .set_index(["CLAIM_VENDOR", "PYYMM", "PAID"])
)

# Use .join to combine based on the index
final_table = (
    new_df_for_join.join(
        old_df_for_join,
        lsuffix="new",
        rsuffix="old"
    )
    .assign(
        difference=lambda DF: DF.valuenew - DF.valueold,
        pct_diff = lambda DF: DF.difference / DF.valueold
    )
    .unstack(level="PAID")
)

print(final_table)
```

The result is

```
                        valuenew                                valueold                            difference                            pct_diff             
PAID                           IP            OP            PR          IP          OP           PR           IP            OP           PR       IP    OP    PR 
CLAIM_VENDOR PYYMM                                                                                                                                              
VENDOR 1     202001           NaN  0.000000e+00           NaN         NaN        0.00          NaN          NaN  0.000000e+00          NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN 
             202002           NaN  0.000000e+00  2.362500e+03         NaN        0.00      3150.00          NaN  0.000000e+00     -787.500      NaN   NaN -0.25 
             202003           NaN  0.000000e+00  1.547000e+03         NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN 
VENDOR 2     202001           NaN           NaN  1.078031e+06         NaN         NaN   1197812.00          NaN           NaN  -119781.200      NaN   NaN -0.10 
             202002           NaN           NaN  1.819538e+06         NaN         NaN   1837917.00          NaN           NaN   -18379.170      NaN   NaN -0.01 
             202003  1.301296e+07           NaN  1.091374e+06         NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN 
VENDOR 3     202001  1.531010e+07  1.123377e+07  2.026918e+07  9005941.61  8987012.39  16890979.44  6304159.127  2.246753e+06  3378195.888      0.7  0.25  0.20 
             202002  9.800652e+06  1.130553e+07  1.857756e+07  5158238.02  7796918.67  16888689.98  4642414.218  3.508613e+06  1688868.998      0.9  0.45  0.10 
             202003  4.243191e+06  2.078419e+08  2.317178e+08         NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN
```